Combination of errors when $1/z = 1/a + 1/b$
It is mentioned directly in every text I could find that, if
$$\frac{1}{z} = \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b}$$
then
$$\frac{\Delta z}{z^2} = \frac{\Delta a}{a^2} + \frac{\Delta b}{b^2}.$$
How we came to this result? Some say to use differentiation, but is it possible to derive this without that, solely on the basis of error analysis? I tried with the following method:
$$z = \frac{ab}{a+b}$$
Now, since $\Delta x/x= \Delta p/p + \Delta q/q$ for $x = p/q$,
$$\frac{\Delta z}{z} = \frac{\Delta(ab)}{ab} + \frac{\Delta (a+b)}{a+b.}$$
Now, if $x = pq$, then $\Delta x = p.\Delta q + q.\Delta p$. So,
$$\frac{\Delta z}{z} = \frac{a∆b + b∆a}{ab} + \frac{\Delta a + \Delta b}{a+b}.$$
Even after putting $z = ab/(a+b)$ in this expression, I couldn't get to the original equation.

This is a rather poor question. You can only apply your method if the two variables $p=ab$ and $q=a+b$ are independent. Here, they are not. This is an elementary mistake. All you have to do is to differentiate the expression as it is without manipulating $1/z$ into $z$.

The relationship is not exact, but it is approximately true if $\Delta z$ is much smaller than $z$, $\Delta a$ is much smaller than $a$, and $\Delta b$ is much smaller than $b$. We can show this without using calculus as follows:
$\displaystyle \frac 1 z = \frac 1 a + \frac 1 b
\\ \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac 1 {z+\Delta z} = \frac 1 {a + \Delta a} + \frac 1 {b + \Delta b}
\\ \Rightarrow \displaystyle \frac 1 z \left( 1+\frac {\Delta z} z \right)^{-1} = \frac 1 a \left( 1 + \frac {\Delta a} a\right) ^{-1} + \frac 1 b \left( 1 + \frac {\Delta b} b\right) ^{-1}$
If $\Delta z$ is much smaller than $z$ then we have
$\displaystyle \left( 1+\frac {\Delta z} z \right)^{-1} = 1 - \frac {\Delta z} z +\left( \frac {\Delta z} z \right)^2 \dots \approx 1 - \frac {\Delta z} z$
so we have
$\displaystyle \frac 1 z \left( 1 - \frac {\Delta z} z \right) \approx \frac 1 a \left( 1 - \frac {\Delta a} a \right) + \frac 1 b \left( 1 - \frac {\Delta b} b \right)
\\ \displaystyle \Rightarrow \frac {\Delta z}{z^2} \approx \frac {\Delta a}{a^2} + \frac {\Delta b}{b^2}$

Thank you very much for the answer. I was looking entire internet but couldn't get this. Very appreciated ☺️

@OmkarDeshmukh it's worth mentioning that this answer just did a Taylor expansion, which is the same as taking a derivative, so it's equivalent to the calculus method you wanted to "avoid". I only say that to encourage you to get more comfortable with the calculus method, which is much more useful in more complicated settings!
